# I asked a aquestion whether women actually care if we love them or not

Tags: discussion

Lots of males spend chocolates and remember birthday because they think loving the women will improve their chance of getting laid. The question is, does it?

It's deleted and I wonder why.

How should I improve the question?

There are people asking whether nice guys finish last, or whether women prefer taller men or richer males.

So it's about what typical women want type of question.

I think it's more of wealth and height and IQ but I may be wrong.

So it's okay to ask whether women prefer taller or richer men but I can't ask whether women prefer men that love them or not. Hei it's important question.

Comment: What's with all the "we" and "us", there are women on the internet too, you know.

Comment: "The reason why this question is important is because knowing what women want can help us easily verify whether an act is consensual or not.". [**No it does not help!**](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/division.html)

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would think that women can't both prefer and be more willing to fall in love with rich, tall and handsome men? I certainly find it a lot easier to fall in love with beautiful, intelligent and successful people, than with those that have the opposite qualities. Love isn't something magic that comes out of thin air.

Comment: Do men actually care whether we love them or not?

Comment: @SamIAm [Uh, … **wrong**.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/there-are-no-girls-on-the-internet)

Comment: So it's okay to ask if nice guys finish last but it's not okay to ask whether girls care if we love them or not? Konrad, the answer to does men care whether women love him or not is no. We care if the girl is pretty. As a man, I don't even know what love is.

Comment: Whether girls care we love them or not is a notable dubious claim. Why is it not relevant for this site?

Comment: Theres no Gurlz on the interwebtubez.

Comment: So it's okay to ask whether women prefer taller or richer men but I can't ask whether women prefer men that love them or not. Hei it's important question. Lots of males spend chocolates and remember birthday because they think loving the women will improve their chance of getting laid. If women doesn't take that into account in sexual selection, why should we love them?

Answer (score 11):

I think, Jim, it's because you've used this site, Economics.SE, and perhaps other StackExchanges too, to repeatedly ask low-quality under-researched questions, often including offensive content.

There is a pattern: you use these sites as a platform to broadcast your own unique views on women, sex, prostitution, and abuse.  Perhaps you'd just be better off with a blog? Maybe you feel that your own blog wouldn't get the audience that you do here; but at least you'd be using the tool as it was intended.

Your questions don't use StackExchange for its intended purpose, and that's why they keep getting closed and deleted.

From the [FAQ](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Skeptics - Stack Exchange is for challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results. Skeptics is about applying skepticism — it is for researching the evidence behind claims you encounter. It is not for speculation, philosophical discussions or investigating original claims.

and

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

Comment: Okay does women care that we love them is a notable claim. I am asking whether it's true or not. How come it's not relevant? What? You mean no man believe that women care that he love her? You mean all those flowers, chocolates, and other nonsenses are not bought? As for political. I am not here to promote. I already prepare something else to promote. I am here to understand reality to ensure I don't promote the wrong thing or state some ridiculously stupid facts that make a fool of my self.

Comment: Here somebody ask http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4409/do-women-prefer-taller-men does women prefer taller men. So women prefer taller men. Women prefer richer men. Does women prefer men wanting to marry her? How much? Do we even know?

Answer (score 6):

I flagged your question as offensive, because, it was.

It wasn't a question, it was just a rant. You didn't even try to word it constructively.

Answer (score 6):

Find a scientist who says this is true.  Quote their claim.  Ask a question that directly questions **that claim**.  If you have other information that backs up the claim or **directly** relates to that claim include it.  Not some logical avenue that you want to take that claim down.  It is really a pretty simple idea.  This is not a site for you to develop your modern day Chauvenist manifesto.