# Wrongly sorted post when sorting by votes

Tags: bug

*[What is with the Zionist censorship of skeptics.se?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1978/5337)* has a score of *-11*.  Therefore, when browsing through the questions sorting by number of votes, I expected it on the last page.  I didn't see it there; the very last post I saw was *[I asked a aquestion whether women actually care if we love them or not](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1514/5337)* with a score of *-8*.  In fact, with a sorting of 50 posts per page, I saw *[What is with the Zionist censorship of skeptics.se?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1978/5337)* at the end of the first page, as in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot showing post with score -11]

This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: It's a part of the Zionist conspiracy

Comment: I reproduced it, but found it at the bottom of the SECOND page. (Vague conjecture I haven't tried to find evidence for: That the 18 upvotes in the answers are being counted in the algorithm.)

Comment: @Oddthinking I have the impression it depends on the number of results per page.

Comment: I have 50 results per page, like you.

Comment: Looks like this issue has come up here before, and been migrated. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95408/sorting-questions-by-votes-is-broken

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, I just wanted to add to the bug, and post pictures of it. I tried to reproduce it, but I got slightly different (but still buggy) results:

At the end of the 1 page, when looking at 50 per page is now this question [Live Tweeting NECSS](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/live-tweeting-necss)

[image: bottom of page 1, 50 ppp]

Even though the start of page 2 in questions with 10 votes:
[image: page 2 top, 50 ppp]

And the Zionist question is at the bottom of page 2:
[image: page 2 bottom, 50 ppp]

When looking in other number of posts per page, it seems that there is a block of questions all out of place. With 30 posts per page:

[part 1 30 ppp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09uc1.png)

[part 2 30 ppp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF1Yx.png)

After this block, on page 3 the 10 votes questions continue.

With 15 posts per page:

[page 4, 15 ppp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7BsU.png)

And again at the next page (5) the 10 votes posts continue.

I've left the screen captures as links and not images, because they take a lot of space.